# Unique pairs for sql table

Tags: mysql

How can I select all the rows in a MySql table which have unique pairs from two columns containing a particular element. In a table with columns A and B, I need all the rows containing x in either of A or B, but with unique (A,B) pairing, order doesn't matter.

For e.g,

```
-----------------
+ id  |  A    |  B
+ 1   |  cat  | dog
+ 2   |  cat  | rat
+ 3   |  deer | cat
+ 4   |  rat  | cat
+ 5   |  dog  | cat
```

The unique pairs in (A,B) are (cat, dog), (cat, rat), and (deer, cat). So I want the rows (1 or 5), (2 or 4) and 3.

I have tried

```
select * from table GROUP BY A, B HAVING (A='cat' OR B='cat')
```

but this gives me rows with both (cat, dog) and (dog, cat). I only need one of those.

How to apply mySql query so as to get only rows with distinct pairs?

Comment: The last id preferably. The output should be rows 5, 4, 3 in that order

Answer (score 0):

Use where and not having because you don't have aggreation function

```
select a, b
from table 
where a = 'x'  or b = 'x'
and (a,b) not in (select b,a from table);
```

use distinct for distinct rows

```
select distinct  a, b
from table 
where a = 'x'  or b = 'x'
and (a,b) not in (select b,a from table);
```

Based on the sample you provided the query below

```
select  id, b, a
from prova
where a = 'cat'  or b = 'cat'
and (a,b) not in (select b,a from prova);
order by id desc
```

return

```
3   deer    cat
2   cat rat
1   cat dog
```

that seems exactly the result you are looking  for

Comment: I dont have 'x' in the same row in both A and B.
For e.g, 1st row - x in Column A, y in Column b
2nd row - y in Column A, x in Column b. I need to get only one of those rows.

Comment: show a sample so i can understand   ... update your question with data sample

Comment: I have update the answer hope is what you are looking for

Comment: A liitle bit, but not totally! This gives me all pairs - true, but also redundant pairs. Like (a,b) and also (b,a). I need only (a, b) or (b,a)

Comment: show sample not word .. edit youe question and update it with a proper clear and exaustive data sample ...

Comment: @GarethHamsik yes,please update your question , do you want (x,y) if they apear only once in the table or what?...its a bit hazy at best your real goal.

Comment: I need rows. Preferably higher id. 5, 4, 3 in that order.

Comment: No, I need rows as in "select *". Also, I need them the highest id first. Is there a function in sql like for loop where I can go through each row, and select the row then?